# how to creat app which works offline

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing an app in crossplatform xamarin.forms using C#, and I am calling webservice to connect to server and retrieving data in JSON format.
Now I want to make this app working even in Offline. So if no network, the app should display some locally stored information and if user add something it should be saved locally and should save when the connection regain.

Anybody please tell me how to do this. Is there any packages avaibale in gitHub?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if internet connection is available. If so you need to call the web-service to get the data. When you receive data store it into the sqlite database. Please refer https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/ for the same.

If internet connection is not available you need to use this sqlite data for the app.

You can always use your sq-lite data for the app. And only use web-service for synchronizing you data with server. This will be proven to be a better approach when your application grows.

Answer (score 0):

Do take a look at [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) !
It will do the heavy lifting for you in reference to storing json in sql for caching purposes.
So it will give you a cached version of your data when internet connection is not available and also based on timing constraints if needed.